# Django Media Files during production with nginx?

Tags: django

How can I serve media files during production?

Within nginx, I have:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    # listen 80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name tweetz.co;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

client_max_body_size 4G;
server_name _;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# Your Django project's media files - amend as required
location /media  {
    alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
}

# your Django project's static files - amend as required
location /static {
    alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
}

# Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
location /static/admin {
   alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
}

location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_pass http://app_server;
}

}
` `# Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
   alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
}

location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_pass http://app_server;
}

}
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Not working. Do I need to change something else?

---

Below my files:

models.py

```
image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='media',blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/static-serve/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
server {
        '/home/django/django_project/static-serve/media/image.jpg'
        location /media {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/django/django_project/static-serve/media/;
        }
    }

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

template

```
<img src="{{ object.profile.image.url }}" class="w3-circle" style="height:106px;width:106px" alt="Avatar">
```

The image source in the browser is: mysite/media/media/myimage.jpg

The image is saved: home/django/django_project/media/media/myimage.jpg

Thank you for any help

Comment: Remove the leading slash, so `upload_to='media'`, not `/media`, by prepending it, you want to upload it to the *root* of your filesystem.

Comment: When you set `upload_to='media'` you're uploading into `.../media/media` because the MEDIA_ROOT is always the base to where files are uploaded. Not a problem (files will be found), but probably not what you're expecting.

Comment: I changed /media to media and it saved the image. Thank you

But the image does not show up in the template.

when I inspect the element I get: src:"/media/media/me.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* prepend the path with a slash, since that means you want to upload your file to a directory named `media` in the *root* of your filesystem.

You can thus for example upload it to:

```
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/',blank=True)
```

If you however omit the [**`upload_to=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), Django will simply upload this to the [**`MEDIA_ROOT`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root).

Comment: I changed /media to media and it saved the image.

 Thank you

 But the image does not show up in the template. 

when I inspect the element I get: src:"/media/media/me.jpg"

Comment: Is the item uploaded to `/home/django/django_project/static-serve/media/image/...`? Did you set `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: Does your user have access to that directory? The directory has as owner/group/... the user with which you run the server?

Comment: I deleted the media folder, saved the image again and it saved without errors. but it still does not show up in the template. Its the profile image associated to the user profile and I am changing the image of the user, I am currently logged in with.

Comment: @Andre: what if you visit the URL of the `<image src="...">` in your browser?

Comment: @Andre: and you added the ` + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` the *root* of the `urlpatterns`? So not an `urls.py` in one of your apps?

Comment: yes urlpatterns = [....
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @Andre: and `static-serve/...` is invalid as well?

Comment: I changed it to /media/, it saves the images into static-serve/media/media. The img src in the browser is mysite/media/media. I dont understand why it is not working

Comment: What do you mean with invalid?

Comment: @Andre: did you fully follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development ?

Comment: Do I need to serve those file from nginx in production? How does it work? There is just a link to nginx in the documentation

Comment: @Ande: yes, you should change Apache/Nginx, like: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50579487/67579